# how to send output files to subdirectories in bash scripting

Tags: bash

I have two folders with names (SRP1234 , SRP2345). Each folder has two subfolders (SRX1, SRX2 for SRP1234 and SRX3, SRX4 for SRP2345). Each subfolder has 4 more subfolders (SRR1,SRR2,SRR3,SRR4 for SRX1  etc) Each SRR floder has one file (with extension .sra) which I have to analyze and place results in SRR subfolders.
But I can't place result files in SRR subdirectory.

Here is the example code which I have written.

```
#!/bin/bash
DATA=/home/data/SRA_Data
for run in $DATA/SRP*
do
  fastq-dump -I --split-files ${run}/SRX*/SRR*.sra --outdir $run/SRX*/SRR*
done
```

**EDITED**

I am not sure I understand what you have, but I think it is like this:

```
 |-SRP1234
 |---SRX1
 |-----SRR1
 |-------file.sra
 |-----SRR2
 |-------file.sra
 |-----SRR3
 |-------file.sra
 |-----SRR4
 |-------file.sra
 |---SRX2
 |-SRP2345
 |---SRX3
 |---SRX4
```

It is unclear (to me) what is in SRX2

Comment: Perhaps you should run that script with `bash -x` and see if it does what you think it does.

Comment: Remember to enclose variables in double quotes: `--outdir "$run"/SRX*/SRR*`

Comment: @ams all the result files are placed in only 1 SRR subfolder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the * wildcard for the input *and* output args is probably not want you want. Simplifying a bit, if you have three subdirectories, foo[123], each containing a single .sra file, the shell expansion would work like this:

```
fastq-dump --split-files foo*/*.sra --outdir foo*

fastq-dump --split-files foo1/a.sra foo2/b.sra foo3/c.sra --outdir foo1 foo2 foo3
```

I presume command doesn't do anything useful with three output directories, and that what you really want is this:

```
fastq-dump --split-files foo1/a.sra --outdir foo1
fastq-dump --split-files foo2/b.sra --outdir foo2
fastq-dump --split-files foo3/c.sra --outdir foo3
```

Is that correct?

If so, your loop should be more granular, perhaps like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
DATA=/home/data/SRA_Data
for directory in $DATA/SRP*/SRX*/SRR*
do
  fastq-dump -I --split-files "${directory}"/*.sra --outdir "${directory}"/
done
```

If you actually want files from multiple SRR directories to be the input for each fastq-dump run, you'll need to describe which directory (directories?) you want to put the output in.